# Mapping issue: correct number of results, however every result is duplicate of first resut

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm new to NHibernate (using latest version) and I am having an issue mapping an object in our generic dataloading application to a database.
The database is third party so we cant make changes there.

Our object is:

```
public class GenericObjectValue
{
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string ObjectTypeId { get; set; }
    public string measurementId { get; set; }
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
    public Double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Datasource tables we use:

```
Table t_data_point
(
    id (PK, int, not null)
    object_id (FK, Varchar(30), not null)
    object_type_id (FK, Varchar(30), not null);
    measurement_id (FK, Varchar(30), not null);
)


Table t_data_point_Value
(
    data_point_id (PK, FK, int, not null)
    timestamp (PK, FK, datetime, not null)
    version (PK, FK, int, not null)
    value (numeric(18,6), not null);
)
```

The mapping i have configured is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Phoenix.Model"     assembly="Phoenix.Common">
 <class name="MeasValue" table="t_data_point_Value">
  <id column="data_point_id" type="int" />
  <property name="Timestamp" column="timestamp "/>
  <property name="Value" column="value"/>

  <join table="t_data_point">
       <key column="id" />
       <property name="measurementId" column="measurement_id" />
       <property name="ObjectId" column="object_id" />
       <property name="ObjectTypeId" column="object_type" />
  </join>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Not sure if i'm doing something stupid or something that just isn't possible but when i run the code for this i get back the correct number of results but the results are just duplications of the first result returned i.e. timestamp and value are the same.

If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when your id is mapped incorrectly, ie to a column that is not unique. Nhibernate will reuse the 1st object it finds in cache with the same id.
There is a free mapping tool that could help point you in the right direction. It wont create the join but it will create the basic columns and id http://nmg.codeplex.com.